# One function with parameters, call it 4 times and keep data separated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let me explain myself

I have this function in my controller

```
function postDashboardsData (dataType, dateFrom, dateTo) {
  Api.post('rotations/' + vm.data[0]._id + '/dashboard', angular.extend({
      type : dataType,
      date_range : {
        from : dateFrom,
        to : dateTo
      }
    }, vm.data))
    .then(function (data) {
      $scope.overallData = data;
    });
}
```

then I call this function 4 times in order to perform the `post` with different data everytime I call the function to the same route:

```
postDashboardsData('overall', $scope.overall, $scope.overall1);

postDashboardsData('clicks-conversion', $scope.clicksConv1, $scope.clicksConv);

postDashboardsData('traffic-sources', $scope.traffic, $scope.traffic1);

postDashboardsData('devices', $scope.devices, $scope.devices1);
```

when the `post` is done, some data comes to the front end in order for me to render it.

The issue I am having is:

The only data is possible to render is the data from the last function I called in the code, because the variable `$scope.overallData = data;` its been overwritten.

I mean: when the first `post` is done, `data` comes with the data from that first post, when the 2nd `post` is done, data comes with the data from the 2nd post, so the variable `$scope.overallData` now is saving the data from the 2nd `post` and and deleting the data from the 1st post, and so on.

So, what can I do in order to perform the `post`, but keeping the data of every `post` separated.

I am trying to do this dynamically so I don't have to create 4 different functions.

Comment: what will you use the collection of `data` for?

Comment: @HassenPy all I need is to render in the view the data coming in those `posts`.

Comment: Why are you storing everything in`$scope.overallData`? Can you elaborate your use case? And why can't  you use a service?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `.then()` from the post function and just return the promise.

```
function postDashboardsData (dataType, dateFrom, dateTo) {
     return  Api.post('rotations/' + vm.data[0]._id + '/dashboard',
       angular.extend({
         type : dataType,
         date_range : {
           from : dateFrom,
           to : dateTo
         }
    }, vm.data));
}
```

and then use chaining on the caller like so:

```
postDashboardsData('overall', $scope.overall, $scope.overall1)
.then(function(data){
    // assign whatever you like
})

postDashboardsData('clicks-conversion', $scope.clicksConv1, $scope.clicksConv)
.then(function(data){
    // assign another variable
});
```

Comment: but actually I am getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: do you return Api.post inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming overallData is an array

```
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.overallData, data);
```

Oh and that will put them in the order the service calls finish, not the order you called the services.